# Change the format of the current excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I just want to ask on how do you change the format of the excel into a new excel. I have examples here that i created manually. But I just want to ask if i could do a background process or a button click to change the format i want. 
Also:
1. How can I get just the id number "40002" in one cell.
2. How can I get the "ABELONON, RYAN" only and remove the string "Employeee: " And the string " (40002)"

[image]
**This is the standard format from the biometrics. And i wanted to change it to the format below.**
[image]
This is the format that I need. Is there any easiest way to change this kind of format? And how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Due to the variety of information gathering you should probably write some vba code to automate the process.

Comment: Some helpful functions you will most likely use: `IsEmpty()`, `InStr()`, `Split()`, `Trim()`, `IsDate()`, `Find()`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "change the format of the excel into a new excel." Do you mean change from 2003 format to 2016 format, create a new workbook, change the layout of data or something else? e.g. One answer is to use `SaveAs`, another answer is `Worksheet.Copy`, another answer may simply be a clean worksheet with Excel Formula to extract the information from the old worksheet.

Comment: Change the format of the first excel(first pic) to the second excel(2nd pic)

Answer (score 1):

There is no immediate answer to your question, I am afraid. Because, any batch operation that involves to read data from one (or multiple) spreadsheets into one single spreadsheet should match some `pattern` in the input spreadsheets.

So, I suggest you provide more information in your question about the specific patterns of your `input` sample (worksheets your want the macro to read from):

- are they in different excel source files?
- are they in the same excel but different worksheets?
- are those worksheets mixed with other worksheets that the macro should not read from?
- given one source worksheet, which is the data pattern the macro should expect to find? For example:

  - once found the first cell from the 1st column of the worksheet with content that starts with `Employee:`
  - first filled in row is a header
  - first filled in row after the header's row is first row of data
  - a **`block of data`** does not contain empty rows and finishes where the first column does not contain a date
  - the structure of a row of data is always:

    1. Date  (date part of a date)
    2. empty
    3. Time (time part of a date)
    4. Time (time part of a date)
  - where (3) and (4) could repeat in some rows
- extract the *employee name* and the *id number*, by expecting to follow the following `Regex` pattern: `Employee:\s*(.*)\((\d+)`
- and copy all the `block of data` by pairing (1) + (3) + (4), and by adding the employee details as two first columns; where (3) and (4) could repeat for certain rows (this last *could* would be tricky)

**In other words:** it is not worthy to make the effort of creating such a macro, if all your source data does not follow one same pattern. But if it does, then update your question and let's see what can be done with it.